# If var not set always results in true, even if its set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

Not sure how to formulate this but here it goes.

I am checking if a var exists (content), if it doesnt i set it.

Problem is next click, it still behaves as if there is no var content. But why??

Here my code:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var load = href + " .content";
    if (!content)
    {
        var content = $('<div>').load(load);
        $(".content").append(content);

    } 
    else 
    {
        var position = content.offset();
        $(document).scrollTop(position);

    }
});
```

It never results to else, so always a click is made the whole load and append function repeats.

Basically how can I record that content for this particular link has been loaded once, so the else function should be performed next time?

Also, what is wrong with my if(!content) statement? Is it because of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript functions determine the scope of an object.  You need to place content in the global scope.  Currently it is created within the anonymous function assigned to the click event handler, so when the function is executed again content is out of scope causing it to return false.

```
var content;
$("#nav a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var load = href + " .content";
    if (!content)
    {
        content = $('<div>').load(load);
        $(".content").append(content);

    } 
    else 
    {
        var position = content.offset();
        $(document).scrollTop(position);

    }
});
```

Comment: ok but in that case it if else will always result in else right?

Comment: No, since we have not assigned content it is `undefined` in javascript `undefined` == false.  Look around for information on truthy and falsey to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the `var content` as a global variable rather than a local one, like you are doing right now. That's why the `if (!content)` result as true always, like:

```
var content;
$("#nav a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var load = href + " .content";
    if (!content) {
        content = $('<div>').load(load);
        $(".content").append(content);
    } else {
        $(document).scrollTop(content.offset());
    }
});
```

Just to show what happens, when value of `content` is not set at first and then set again:

```
var content;
console.log(content);  // undefined 
console.log(!content); // true 

content = 'text';
console.log(content);  // text  
console.log(!content); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for answering the first question about the checking if var exists.

I ended up ditching this whole concept it turned out the

```
one()
```

function is what I needed all along. In order to only execute a function once and another function on all following clicks.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Ajaxify Navi
        $("#nav a").one("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var load = href + " .content";
            var content = $('<div>').load(load);
            $(".content").append(content);
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var position = content.offset().top;
                $(document).scrollTop(position);
                $("body").append(position);
            });
        });
});
```

What this is is the following:

1st click on a button loads content via ajax and appends it, second click on the same button only scrolls to said content.